# Direction of propagating wave in quantum barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

> Consider a step potential $V(x)$ where
>   \begin{align}
> V(x) & = 0; \quad x\leq 0 \\
> V(x) & = V_0; \quad x> 0 
> \end{align}
>   Now consider the case where $E_0<V_0$. The solutions of the time independent Schrodinger equation are:
>   \begin{align}
> \psi_L(x) & = A e^{i\theta x} + B e^{-i\theta x} \\
> \psi_R(x) & = C e^{K x} + D e^{-K x}
> \end{align}

I understand that for $x > 0$, the amplitude $C =0$ as when $x \to\infty$ then the wavefunction goes to zero.
However for $x \leq 0$, the wavefunction as I understand it is made up of an incident and reflected wave. I am confused how to understand which one is the incident and which is reflected.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
[image]

Here is an extract from my notes which clarify that $$ A e^{i\theta x}$$ term is the one which is the incoming wave but i am still unsure why this is the case

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to tell in which direction the waves are moving without looking at the time dependence. According to the Schrodinger equation the time dependence of $\Psi_L$ is given by:

$$\Psi_L= A e^{i(\theta x - \omega t)} +B e^{i(-\theta x - \omega t)},$$

with $\omega = \frac{\hbar \theta^2}{2m}$. To see how the first term behaves, set B to $0$. We are left with a function which at $t=0$ has a constant modulus and a phase that varies in space. Pick your favorite point on this curve, e.g., $\Psi_L=A$ and analyze how the $x$ value for which $\Psi_L=A$ moves as we increase t.

For $t=0$ we obtain $\Psi_L=A$ when $x=0$ (there are many other solutions which we ignore). As $t$ increases, the $x$ value for which $\Psi_L=1$ increases:

$$\Psi_{L,B=0}=A$$
$$ A e^{i(\theta x - \omega t)} =A $$
$$ \theta x - \omega t = 0 $$ 
$$ x_{\Psi_L=A} = \frac{\omega}{\theta} t$$

We see that the point for which $\Psi_L=A$ moves to the right as time progresses. It does so with a velocity $v=\frac{\omega}{\theta}$ We might have chosen any other point and would have obtained the same velocity. This is why we say the wave travels to the right.

For the second term of $\Psi_L$, a similar analysis will show a left moving wave.

In general any function $f(ax+bt)$, with $a$ and $b$ real and positive, describes a left moving function, while any function $f(ax-bt)$ describes a right moving function.

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: @DavidAbraham I updated the answer

Comment: I am unsure if that is correct since i know that the A
e^i(θx+ωt) is the term that is moving to the right (i.e incident upon the barrier)

Comment: Please see the extract from my notes which clarify what i am saying.

Comment: @DavidAbraham You are completely right. I made a mistake in calculating the time dependence. the term in the exponent should be $-i\omega t$ instead of $+i\omega t$. I adapted the answer.

Comment: surely deciding the sign of wt is arbitrary... so why should it make a difference.

Comment: @DavidAbraham it is not arbitrary. You can check that the equation for $\Psi_L$ now obeys the schrodinger equation, while it did not with the inverted sign before $\omega$

Comment: The sign convention in the schrodinger equation can be considered arbitrary though, but this leads to a completely different discussion, for which a new question would be appropriate.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but i am confused as it seems that -iwt would also also satisfy the Time indepdent schrodinger equation so i am sunure why we we would make it negative rather than positive. Because if it is positive then the direction of propogation would swap between the two terms.

Comment: @DavidAbraham You should look at the time-dependent schrodinger equation. There is only one sign of $\omega$ for which the time-dependent schrodinger equation is obeyed.